# Using Google Closure Compiler with React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, bundling-and-minification, google-closure-compiler

I'm wondering about the option of integrating Google Closure Compiler with Create-React-App, or React in general, to minimize bundle size.

- Is it possible?
- Will it support all features of React at the same level as Webpack? (I can see issues with Code Splitting, and components being inlined improperly)
- Should it be used instead of Webpack or in addition?
- Assuming it is used instead of Webpack and advanced optimizations are enabled, will it usually make bundle size smaller?
- What are the code changes required for supporting Google Closure Compiler in this context?
- Is there any documentation or example projects for doing this? Preferably using Create-React-App.

Answer (score 1):

The Closure Compiler used in simple mode should be compatible with almost all JavaScript.   Setting the language_out to something modern will avoid limitations of transpiration.

Using ADVANCED, generally, requires coding to its restrictions.